# Ckeditor Toolbar Dropdown Element

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ck-editor 3 and have written custom code which will destroy ck-editor instance on blur action.

Problem i am facing is if i select any of the drop-down boxes from toolbar for e.g. style,size.
then on-blur event of instance is called and as per code its gets destroyed due to which i am not able to format it and editor gets closed.

I don't want to prevent on-blur event as a whole but wanted to prevent only when any of the toolbar element is accessed.

Is there any way to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: Do you use the blur destruction to simulate an inline editor? If so, how about updating to CKE 4 and using the actual inline editing?

Comment: Any news? This is a little old, did you solve it?

Comment: Have you get solved it? i am gettting the same issue in ckeditor 4.3.3.